# Function to remove duplicates from Google Form

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I was  trying to make a script for a google spreadsheet that would remove duplicate entries that were submitted via a google form.  Essentially the google form writes the entries to the google spreadsheet and I wanted any google form entry that were a duplicate to an entry already submitted through the form, to be removed automatically.  This is the code that I have now:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {  
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("13ggBeSGGxhI291uPcIr0RudwxxKUigtNEN750Q2hCBM");
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 var newData = new Array();
 for(i in data){
   var row = data[i];
   var duplicate = false;
   for(j in newData){
     if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
       duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
       newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

I know parts of it are still incorrect so i was hoping someone could help me get a better idea of what I'm doing wrong so that I can make the necessary corrections.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you what is incorrect? Is it working and you just want a code review or are there particular issues with your code?

Comment: It's not working.  This is the error "TypeError: Cannot find function clearContents in object Spreadsheet. (line 17, file "")" even though clearContents() is a function of Spreadsheet (it's on google's API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened a **Spreadsheet** object, you also need to open the actual **sheet** (One spreadsheets has one or more sheets).
The [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) class has a method `clearContents()`, a [spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) doesn't.

Try  `SpreadsheetApp.openById("13ggBeSGGxhI291uPcIr0RudwxxKUigtNEN750Q2hCBM").getSheetByName(whateverYourResponseSheetNameIsAsAString);`.

As for why the Spreadsheet class supports `getValues()` but not `clearContents()`, I don't know, it seems inconsistent. For the former it is implicitly running `getActiveSheet()`.